# NgxMatLuxonAdapter (Ngx-Mat-DateTimePicker) setting values on immutable object

Tags: angular, datetimepicker, luxon

my projects used the Material DatePicker with the MatLuxonAdapter. Now we need a DateTIMEPicker and came across this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-material-components/datetime-picker

Since this only supports Moment and we use Luxon I wanted to extend on the Luxon Adapter for the DatePicker to make use of this DateTimePicker, but I seem to be stuck.

I extended and implemented the classes I wanted to use, I don't think this is a good practice, but Luxons DateAdapter is the basis I want to use.

```
export class MyDateAdapter extends LuxonDateAdapter implements NgxMatDateAdapter<DateTime> {}
```

I then implemented all methods of NgxMatDateAdapter. It's kinda working. I'm only having trouble setting a new time. There are three setter methods for hour, minute and second and I cannot make it work with Luxon since it's immutable.

```
setHour(date: DateTime, value: number): void {
  date.set({hour:value}); // doesn't work since it will not change date
}

setHour(date: DateTime, value: number): void {
  date = date.set({hour:value}); // also doesn't work
}
```

what can I do?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? On the surface, it doesn't seem like there's a good option

Comment: @ScottScowden I just ran into the same problem and solved it by wrapping luxons `DateTime` into an object. So I basically extended `NgxMatDateAdapter<{ time: DateTime }>` and then modify the object by replacing the `DateTime` in it.

Comment: @ScottScowden I never got a satisfying solution and with time being of the essence at the project we did drop the DateTimeAdapter and used the html native time element in addition to the DatePicker. Sorry